# I build my website with MERN stack. I published my website but I can't login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm new to publish a MERN stack website.
I use an Ionos vps s linux server. I also use Cloudflare and apache2 to publish it. The frontend is working. My backend seems not to work at all.

I get the following message in my console, when I press the login button:

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>Planetbots</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.2ffabd23.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.82c0520a.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

Here's my code for the Login.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Login.scss";
import newRequest from "../../utils/newRequest";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('frontend called')
        try {
            console.log('frontend ca')
            const res = await newRequest.post("/auth/login", { username, password });
            console.log('const res', res.data)
            if (res.data && res.data.username === username && res.data.password === password) {
                console.log("Login successfull");
                localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(res.data));
                navigate("/");
                console.log(res.data)
                console.log('if')
            } else {
                console.log(res.data);
                console.log('else')
                // Handle failed registration here, if needed
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Frotend error:", err);
            console.log('hallo')
            // Handle other errors here, if needed
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="login">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Sign in</h1>
                <label htmlFor="">Username</label>
                <input
                    name="username"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                />

                <label htmlFor="">Password</label>
                <input
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
                {error && error}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Here is my newRequest.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const newRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://planetbots.de/api/",
    withCredentials: true,
});

export default newRequest;
```

Here's my server.js:

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import userRoute from "./routes/user.route.js";
import gigRoute from "./routes/gig.route.js";
import orderRoute from "./routes/order.route.js";
import conversationRoute from "./routes/conversation.route.js";
import messageRoute from "./routes/message.route.js";
import reviewRoute from "./routes/review.route.js";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.route.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, join } from 'path';
import https from 'https';
import fs from 'fs';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, '/build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/root/bots/ssl/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/root/bots/ssl/cert.pem')};
const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)

dotenv.config();
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

const connect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB);
        console.log("Connected to mongoDB!");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

const corsOptions = {
    origin: "https://planetbots.de", // Gib hier die URL deines Frontends an
    credentials: true, // Erlaube das Senden von Cookies von der Frontend-Domain
};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/gigs", gigRoute);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRoute);
app.use("/api/conversations", conversationRoute);
app.use("/api/messages", messageRoute);
app.use("/api/reviews", reviewRoute);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const errorStatus = err.status || 500;
    const errorMessage = err.message || "Something went wrong!";
    return res.status(errorStatus).send(errorMessage);
});

const port = 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
    connect();
});
```

Here's my auth.controller.js:

```
export const login = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
        console.log(req.body.username)
        console.log('Login function called im try catch')

        if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found!"));

        const isCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
        console.log(req.body.username && req.body.password)
        if (!isCorrect)
            return next(createError(400, "Wrong password or username!"));

        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                id: user._id,
                isSeller: user.isSeller,
            },
            process.env.JWT_KEY
        );

        const { password, ...info } = user;
        
        res
            .cookie("accessToken", token, {
                secure: false,
                httpOnly: true,
            })
            .status(200)
            .send(info);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('hi')
        next(err);
    }
};
```